# git push wrong email GitHub

Tags: git

Hi I recently started using Git and GitHub so this question might be a dumb one. Everything was working perfectly. I could push and pull files and everything was updating correctly. Then I tried to commit a file to see how it works and suddenly everything stopped working. Every time I try to update a remote repo using the `git push origin master` command, the email it shows is different from the one I set with the `git config --global user.email "myemail"` command (it shows `myusername@github.com`). How can I get things to work again?

Comment: Can you copy the output when you type `git push origin master`?

Comment: When I run `git push`, I see `git@github.com`. Is that confusing you?

Comment: What is the output of your `git config --list` command?

Comment: Apparently everything is working now. The output was: Everything is up to date. I was able to update Github repo by using `git add .` then `git add -u` and then `git commit -m "A message"`. After that when I used `git push origin master`, the remote repo got updated. Thanks for your help guys. And btw, do you need to do those steps (add and commit) every time you change something locally?

Comment: @Mark: Yup everytime. You need to stage the modified files first by using `git add <filename>` or `git add --all` for all the files and then commit them using `git commit -m "Message"`

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much @Chenchs for your help. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your global config is not overridden by your local config (check the output of `git config --local user.email`)

> do you need to do those steps (add and commit) every time you change something locally?

Yes, the index (staging area) which is modified by git add is what allows you to prepare your commit (register what you want to commit).

The greatest benefit is the [Interactive Staging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging), where you pick out of a set of important modifications only the subset you want for your next commit (instead of making one giant commit).

Comment: Great! Thanks @VonC for the info, really appreciated. :)